# How to setup JNDI for Sun App Server 8.2

Tags: java, datasource, jndi

http://localhost:8080/rtsclient/loginform.faces
Url  jnp://localhost:1099
Application Server Type  jboss40
Datasource  jdbc/ilogDataSource
User  rtsAdmin
Password  rtsAdmin

The above is for jboss.
Now i have deployed RTS onto Sun Application Server. And i want to configure the jndi such that.
My RTS client can actually access it.

How do i go about this?
I asked this question here

http://forums.ilog.com/brms/index.php?topic=803.0

i know it is quite specific.
But how to do it generally in sun application server?

Answer (score 1):

I think creating a ***jndi.properties*** file in your project root with the following should be enough.

```
org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=localhost
org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=1099
java.naming.security.principal=rtsAdmin
java.naming.security.credentials=rtsAdmin
```

There are also a few other things configurable if you need to

```
java.naming.provider.url=...
java.naming.factory.initial=...
java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming
java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl
```

A less flexible method is also available. On startup provide the needed values to the InitialContext()-constructor as a Hashmap

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.put(Context. ...., "...");
e.g.
prop.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "rtsAdmin");
prop.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "rtsAdmin");
InitialContext context = new InitialContext(prop);
```

Check [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/api/javax/naming/Context.html#field_summary) what you can set via the constructor